# Actionbarsherlock with Viewpagerindicator

Tags: android, themes, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I have an app that is using Viewpagerindicator.  I am using the tabs portion of it. I use a black background and the default blue indicator color.  I wanted to add an actionbar to my app so I started using Actionbarsherlock. In order to get my tabs to show an the action bar to show I created my own them which is called in my manifest file. The theme I created is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is our main ActionBarSherlock theme -->
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

<style name="Theme.VPI" parent="Theme.Styled">
      <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TitlePageIndicator</item>
      <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>
      <item name="vpiTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator.Text</item>

</style>    

</resources>
```

When I run the app, I get my blue indicator color but the background of the entire app is white.

Originally I was how this code inside:

```
<style name="Theme.VPI" parent="Theme.Styled">
   <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
</style>
```

That gave me red indicators with a white background.  I know the custom tabs are red with a white background and that is why I changed it from CustomTabPageIndicator to Widget.TabPageIndicator.  However, I am still getting an all white background.

I have tried to just make my layout have a black background inside of my pageviewer, however when I do that, my buttons become really dark and unreadable.

My main question is to find where I can change the color inside of the Viewpagerindicator theme.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Visit this example; [Making ActionBarSherlock and ViewPagerIndicator play nice](http://droidista.blogspot.com/2012/08/making-actionbarsherlock-and.html)
> >
> > Possible Bug in that example; [Android - SupportMapFragment with GoogleMaps API 2.0 giving IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124354/android-supportmapfragment-with-google-map-api-2-0-giving-error/)
> >
> > > > #### *Good Luck..!!*